# JavaFX - Button click won't display String from TextField

Tags: javafx

I am designing a contacts list application, and so far I am stuck on something fairly simple. Currently for testing purposes, I want it so that when I hit the "saveButton" Button, it prints the text entered from the "nameField" TextField into the console. Here is my code:

```
public class Controller {

    // main_activity window objects
    @FXML private Button btnAdd;
    @FXML private Button btnSearch;
    @FXML private TableColumn nameCol;
    @FXML private TableColumn phoneCol;
    @FXML private TableColumn emailCol;

    // add_contact window objects
    @FXML private TextField phoneField;
    @FXML private TextField nameField;
    @FXML private TextField emailField;
    @FXML private Button saveButton;

    @FXML
    public void addContact(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("add_contact.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Add Contact");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 385, 285));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void saveContact(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
         System.out.println(nameField.getText());
    }
}
```

FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="145.0" layoutY="22.0" text="Add Contact">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField id="nameField" fx:id="nameField" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="77.0" onAction="#saveContact" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="373.0" />
      <TextField id="phoneField" fx:id="phoneField" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="143.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="373.0" />
      <TextField id="emailField" fx:id="emailField" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="205.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="373.0" />
      <Button id="saveButton" fx:id="saveButton" layoutX="327.0" layoutY="255.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="59.0" text="Save" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="52.0" text="Name" />
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="118.0" text="Phone" />
      <Label layoutX="16.0" layoutY="188.0" text="Email" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post the FXML file.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/yKJ0WMXa here ya go :)

Comment: Post it in the question please.

Comment: The `saveButton` has no `onAction` attribute.

Comment: Holy God I'm a dumbass. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button does not have onAction attribute in FXML specifing which method should be called once the button has been pressed.